# CruiseControl Next Build Time: Retrieve/Display

Tags: build, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, continuous-deployment, cruisecontrol

I am looking for a way to retrieve the value of the next build date/time in CruiseControl. This value is displayed in both the CCTray app as well as the CC Dashboard/Farm Report (../ccnet/ViewFarmReport.aspx), so it must be stored somewhere on the build machine or in the CruiseControl local memory (or even a listener file somewhere). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCTray gets the information by querying the CruiseControl-server. Information about the status of the projects can be read from the XML returned from `XmlStatusReport.aspx`.

For example, the response from `http://buildserver/ccnet/X/Y/XmlStatusReport.aspx` is something like:

```
<Projects CCType="CCNet">
    <Project name="MyProject"
             category="MyCategory"
             activity="Sleeping"
             lastBuildStatus="Success"
             lastBuildLabel="42"
             lastBuildTime="2017-02-21T15:51:12.0880951+01:00"
             nextBuildTime="2017-02-21T20:10:43.3853446+01:00"
      ...>
    </Project>
</Projects>
```

Which tells us the `nextBuildTime` of the project `MyProject`. You can [browse the source-code](https://github.com/ccnet/CruiseControl.NET/blob/3cf8be76d80b9984984b8f42c6035745ac0381b9/project/Remote/CruiseServerHttpClient.cs) for CruiseControl.Net for more info.